# Enum to Class with lambda expression

Tags: c#

I have an Enum and a Class:

```
public enum Colors { Red = 1, Yellow = 2 }

public class Color {
  public int Value { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Can I create a List from the enum Colors values using a lambda expression?

Thank you,
Miguel

Comment: I'm guessing `Name` is supposed to be a `string`, not an `int`.

Comment: Yes. correct. Just fixed it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assumes you meant for the `Name` property to be a `string` instead of an `int`

```
( ( IEnumerable<int> )Enum.GetValues(typeof(Colors)) )
    .Select(ev =>
    new Color()
    {
        Value = ev,
        Name = Enum.GetName(typeof(Colors), ev)
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I tried that solution too. Doesn't compile for me error CS1061: 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found

Comment: same issue - I've never actually tried linq with System.Array but it does not appear to play well unless I'm missing something. error CS1061: 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'AsEnumerable' and no extension method 'AsEnumerable' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array'

Comment: What a pain haha... cast the resulting array from `Enum.GetValues` to `IEnumerable<int>`

Comment: Total pain - I just punted and went the GetNames and parse for value.

Comment: The above works.  I guess I've never tried the LINQ extensions on an array before, but it makes sense as they're all extensions of `IEnumerable<T>` and an array only implements `IEnumerable`

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a list of the enum values. You don't need to create a custom `Color` class.

```
var myColorsList = Enum.GetValues(typeof (Colors)).Cast<Colors>().ToList();
```

If you really want to use your `Color` object:

```
var myColors = Enum.GetValues(typeof (Colors)).Cast<Colors>()
                   .Select(x => new Color{Value = (int)x, Name = x.ToString()})
                   .ToList();
```

Comment: You answered first, and perfectly addressed the question asked ... next time, remember to mind-read ;)

Answer (score 1):

First change the Name property to a string and then try this:

```
public enum Colors { Red = 1, Yellow = 2 }

public class Color
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var colorClasses = from name in Enum.GetNames(typeof(Colors))
                       select
                       new Color()
                       {
                           Value = (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(Colors), name),
                           Name = name
                       };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Theres at least two ways to do it (though I can't imagine why you'd need to):

```
static void Main( string[] args )
{
  List<Color> colorList1 = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Colors)).Cast<Colors>().Select( c => new Color( c.ToString(), (int)c ) ).ToList() ;
  List<Color> colorList2 = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Colors)).Zip( Enum.GetValues(typeof(Colors)).Cast<int>() , (n,v)=> new Color(n,v)).ToList() ;
  return ;
}
class Color
{
  public Color( string name , int value )
  {
    Name = name ;
    Value = value ;
  }
  public string Name { get ; set ;  }
  public int    Value { get ; set ; }
  public override string ToString()
  {
    return string.Format( "{0}:{1}" , Name , Value ) ;
  }
}
enum Colors
{
  Red    = 1 ,
  Orange = 2 ,
  Yellow = 3 ,
  Green  = 4 ,
  Blue   = 5 ,
  Indigo = 6 ,
  Violet = 7 ,
}
```